# Django - post_init signal is called on Model instance save & before instance is even created. Why?

Tags: python, django, signals

I am trying to write a small application that receives video files, and convert them to a uniform format after they have been uploaded (thus added to the database). I have searched the web for the best solution for this, and have decided to use Django's signals with [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/). But for now I'm trying to create a proof-of-concept to see if it works.

I'm trying to execute a `video_repalce()` method after a new video has been uploaded (thus, a new row has been added to database). But the signal doesn't work right, or I didn't understand how the whole system works.

I'm using *Django 1.2.3* with pre-defined signal `django.db.models.signals.post_init`, which [*should* be called after a model has been instantiated](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.post_init) (thus, a new row was added to the database).

```
from django.core.files.base import File
from django.db.models.signals import post_init
import os
import os.path
import subprocess

class Project(models.Model):
    video = models.FileField(upload_to="projects/videos")

    def replace_video(self):
        """Replace original video with an updated one."""

        # Video conversion process code goes here,
        # resulting in a new external video file.

        self.video.delete() # Delete the original video.
        self.video.save("newfile.webm", File(open("path/to/newfile.webm") ,"wb"))) # Save the new video instead.

        self.save() # Commit everything to database.

        os.remove("path/to/newfile.webm") # Remove original video copy after it was commited (copied) into the DB.

# ...
# ...

def handle_new_project(sender, **kwargs): 
    """Handels some additional tasks for a new added project. i.e. convert video to uniform format."""

    project = kwargs['instance']
    project.replace_video()

# Call 'Project.replace_video()' every time a new project is added.
post_init.connect(handle_new_project, sender=Project, dispatch_uid="new_project_added")
```

However, post_init is called *not only* when a new model instance is created, but also...:

1. Before the model is even instantiated. What I mean is, it's called when I exeucte the server for the first time, when there's not even a single row of data in the database (thus, no Model objects should be instantiated). The instance's `self.pk` is `None`!
2. When `save()`-ing a model. The code above is also executed when I hit `self.save()`.

Practically, it not working according to the docs.

What am I doing wrong? Remember that this is a proof-of-concept. I intend to move the code to [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) after I see it's working. But, if the signals don't work right, [Celery](http://celeryproject.org/) won't help - The signal will always be resent a couple of times whenever I `save()` or update a video.

Do you think I shouldn't call `save()` inside the `replace_video()` method? So where should I call it? Which signal should I choose? `post_save` isn't a good option because it's also called whenever I hit `save()`.

Comment: You mention the signal is always sent when you execute the server, what happens if you just open a shell `manage.py shell` and import the model?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

You seem to have a bit of confusion over what it means to instantiate an object. It has nothing whatever to do with the database. This instantiates a model object without saving it to the database, in which case its pk will be None:

```
MyObject(field1='foo', field2='bar')
```

and this (indirectly) instantiates an object by getting it from the database:

```
MyObject.objects.get(field1='baz')
```

The `post_init` signal will be sent in both of these cases, even though neither of them has anything to do with saving to the database.

If you want something to happen when you save, either override the `save` method itself, or use the `pre_save` or `post_save` signals. You can check there whether or not the object has been previously saved, by verifying if its `pk` is None.

Comment: I always found the `pk is None` method a bit scary (it's possible to set it manually), but I guess it's the only way there is.

Comment: I eventually used `post_save`, and added a condition to check if I need to replace the video. Thus, I'm not calling `save()` recursively.

Comment: thank you for the clarification of the confusion. I am so surprised that post_init is also invoked when we call get method.

Comment: Had same problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

I know the question is old but I had a similar problem and easy solution for that is just using post_save signal and check if created

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=YourSender) 
   def when_init(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
      if created:
         ...
```